# How to give a more specific role, like read, create, update, and delete? here I use laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

For now the role that I created has been running properly, but when I add read, create, update and delete I have difficulty. this is what I expect:

[my expectations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwSLq.png)

This is my roles table:

[roles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8maAn.png)

This is my user_role table:

[user_role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43R9M.png)

This is my User Model:

```
public function roles() {
    // return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    //test
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot([
        'rd',
        'cr',
        'up',
        'dl'
    ]);
}

public function hasAnyRoles($roles) {
    return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('kd_role', $roles)->first();
}

public function hasAnyRole($role) {
    return null !== $this->roles()->where('kd_role', $role)->first();
}

public function karyawan()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Karyawan', 'nik', 'nik');
}

public function roleUser() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\RoleUser');
}
```

This is my User Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $id = Crypt::decrypt($id);
    //Auth user
    $authUser = Auth::user()->id;
    $authAdmin = Auth::user()->is_admin;

    if ($authUser == $id && $authAdmin == false) {
        return redirect('/users')->with('warning', 'Kamu Tidak Dapat Mengubah Data Dirimu Sendiri.');
    }

    return view('layouts.user.edit')->with(['user' => User::with('roles')->find($id), 'roles' => Role::all()]);
    // Test
    // $user = User::with('roles')->find($id);
    // return  json_encode($user);
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="role"
    class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Role</label>
<!-- Input text validasi -->
<div class="col-sm-10">
    @if ($roles->count())
    @foreach($roles as $role)
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input name="roleUser[]" value="{{$role->id}}" {{ $user->hasAnyRole($role->kd_role)?'checked':'' }} id="customCheck{{$role->id}}" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck{{$role->id}}">{{$role->nm_role}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{-- Testing --}}
                <div class="col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input name="create" value="" id="customCheck111" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label">Read</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input name="create" value="" id="customCheck111" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label">Create</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input name="update" value="" id="customCheck222" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label">Update</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-inline mr-3">
                    <input name="delete" value="" id="customCheck333" class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
                    <label class="custom-control-label">Delete</label>
                </div>
                {{-- End Testing --}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use laravel spatie package. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission it will give you all priviliges

Comment: I have tried this before, but the case is different from the case I have, thanks for the response

Comment: You can use , Entrust package for Roles and Permission Module.